# GLSurfaceView device orientation change, black screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Im porting an iOS game to Android.

Im using as template the GL2JNI example from the latest NDK, and have added inside GL2JNIActivity.java/onCreate mView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause( true ); to preserve the EGL context but it as soon the device orientation change the screen is all black.

I've research on this and some suggests to reload all textures, shaders, geometry etc... But that is not an option for me (too slow to reload).

Is there any way to handle like on iOS multiple devices orientation using on OpenGLES2 view on Android? If yes how can it be done without reloading everything. I've seen like Unity games doing it... so it must be possible right?

TIA!

Comment: To answer my own question adding screenSize in the manifest (android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">) did the job.

Comment: care to share how you handled the GLSurfaceView in `onConfigurationChanged()` method?